# Jquery Ajax success wont firing instead complete event works

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using Angular Js with JQuery in a noodles way. See my code below.

### Code

```
app.controller('ClassController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.ShowHideNoRecords = false;
    var credentials = new Object();
    credentials.SourceName = "###";
    credentials.SourcePassword = "###";
    credentials.UserName = "###";
    credentials.UserPassword = "##";
    credentials.SiteId = [-99];
    var locationIds = [1];
    var startDate = Date.today();
    var endDate = startDate;
    var dto = { credentials: credentials, startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate, locationId: locationIds };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'MbApiConnector.asmx/GetAllClasses',
        data: JSON.stringify(dto),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        },
        complete: function (msg) {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.Classes = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(msg.responseText).d);
                if ($scope.Classes.length > 0) {
                    $scope.checkin = function (id) {
                        dto = { credentials: credentials, classId: id };
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: 'MbApiConnector.asmx/Checkin',
                            data: JSON.stringify(dto),
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "jsonp",
                            complete: function (msg) {
                                alert(msg.responseText);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $scope.ShowHideNoRecords = true;
                }
            });
        }

    });
});
```

Everything is working fine with this code. I knew its a bad idea mixing the two but my app was already developed in Jquery Ajax and we are upgrading with Angular JS but with lesser changes. So I came up with this solution. 
Anyways, my issues is that jquery ajax success function is not get called. I am able to receive data from the webservice , but inside the complete method, as you can see in the code above.

Can you explain me why its behaving so?

Comment: You would see something similar to this behavior if jQuery couldn't parse the response as the dataType that you specified (jsonp). I see you running `JSON.parse(JSON.parse(`. I think jquery wants the response in a format where you only have to run one JSON.parse

Answer (score 0):

May be Jquery fails to parse it as the result may not be in JSON format, try to find the error using error callback function. You could try with dataType : 'json'.
error: function (err) { alert(err) }